# In C# (Windows Forms specifically), is there any way to tell if the mouse has three buttons?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to be able to assign middle mouse button functionality to another button if there is no middle mouse button. Is there any way to check to see how many buttons there are?

Comment: You can use the WinAPI function [GetSystemMetrics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getsystemmetrics) with the flag `SM_CMOUSEBUTTONS`, which retrieves the number of mouse buttons. [PInvoke](http://pinvoke.net) should be able to provide a C# declaration of the function for you.

Comment: There are a lot of utilities that do what you want, check eg [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/326028/emulate-middle-mouse-click-on-a-two-button-mouse-in-windows-7) as SuperUser. I doubt *any* mouse comes with only two buttons nowadays, but some very old touchpads do - even then, they probably allow emulating the third button https://superuser.com/questions/145659/emulate-middle-mouse-click-by-pressing-the-two-buttons-at-the-same-time

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Using a utility is silly. You could also just ask the user *Does your mouse have 3 buttons?* when your app starts. The poster isn't looking to use an external utility. The question is tagged C#, which clearly means they're looking for a programming solution. If the *utility* can figure it out, so can your own code.

Comment: [SystemInformation.MouseButtons](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.systeminformation.mousebuttons?view=netcore-3.1) gives you the number of buttons.

Comment: @KenWhite The OS may already provide a solution so no coding is needed. There's no better solution than not having to do anything

Comment: @KenWhite never mind that one could ask where did a two-button mouse come from? There haven't been any of those for almost two decades. Some >10yo touchpads had only two buttons but *already* emulated a middle button. So why the question, why can't the OS or mouse driver already handle this?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: How did I misunderstand *There are a lot of utilities that do what you want, check this link*? What else does that mean than that you're recommending the poster consider using a utiltity? What other purpose would that sentence serve? If it's not what you meant, why did you include it at all? If the poster feels they have a need to check for a three-button mouse, it's none of our business why. The question aaked should be answered when possible.

Comment: @KenWhite that the computer may already contain one in the form of a touchpad driver

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: You'd still have to have the user open the touchpad driver software of tell you whether they had the third button or not. Once again, the OP is very clearly wanting to do it from their own code, not anything external (which I also pointed out in my first comment to you).